# How to create collection in mongo at startup with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: genesystems-apps_mysql
    image: mysql:5.6.33
    ports:
      - "3360:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    entrypoint:
      sh -c "
      echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS genesys_precon;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
      /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      "
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]

  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:5.0.19
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=user
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db:delegated
      - ./init/init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js:ro

  genesystems-apps:
    container_name: genesystems-apps
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8094:8094"
      - "8095:8095"
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

The mysql database creates it well paying attention to the file that creates the different tables.
instead, for mongo it doesn't appear to be querying the init.js file, since when I enter the database once it's started, it's empty.

init.js:

```
db.createCollection('companies', {capped: false});
db.companies.insert([
    {
        "_id": "f1a-98b4-3697d76a2ed2",
        "version": {
            "$numberLong": "0"
        },
        "externalCode": "E-0142",
        "countryCode": "ES",
        "name": "IVA",
        "createdDate": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1223703"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedDate": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "17223703"
            }
        }
    }
]);

db.createCollection('groups', {capped: false});
db.groups.insert([
    {
        "_id": "bc8caa5e-68ea9a3f362d",
        "version": {
            "$numberLong": "0"
        },
        "externalCode": "E-066",
        "name": "Antonio",
        "company": {
            "$ref": "companies",
            "$id": "f1a-98b4-3697d76a2ed2"
        },
        "createdDate": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1587223729"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedDate": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "158723729"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Highlight that I would like to be able to access the database without a username or password.
What I can do?

I am seeing the database with mongo compass, although I have also done it with mongo-express.
doesn't seem to be getting to init.js.
the init directory is at the same height as data, and the data in data is actually created